# Which memory allocator is used by "py-polars" in my "linux" docker image ? (mimalloc or jemalloc)

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a "linux" docker image *(base image -> python:3.10-slim-bullseye)* on which i have polars installed *(related wheel -> polars-0.17.13-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl)*.

For various reason, I want to better understand the memory allocated by my application.
I was convinced that on such a "Linux" image, the Jemalloc allocator was in-use and i tried to activate/print some "jemalloc" stats.
I therefore ran my application with the following environment variables:
`MALLOC_CONF=stats_print:true`

I was expecting some jemalloc statistics to be displayed when my process exits but it is not the case *(i.e. nothing was displayed*).

I also gave a try with:
`JEMALLOC_SYS_WITH_MALLOC_CONF=stats_print:true`

It was the same (no statistics are displayed).

I may miss something and another environment variable has to be set in order to have the jemalloc stats displayed but i was not able to figure out how i can have those "jemalloc" stats displayed.

I finally gave a try with some "mimalloc" related environment variables (mainly `MIMALLOC_VERBOSE=1`) and here it displayed some "mimalloc" related messages:

```
mimalloc: option 'show_errors': 1
mimalloc: option 'show_stats': 1
mimalloc: option 'eager_commit': 1
mimalloc: option 'deprecated_eager_region_commit': 0
mimalloc: option 'deprecated_reset_decommits': 0
mimalloc: option 'large_os_pages': 0
mimalloc: option 'reserve_huge_os_pages': 0
mimalloc: option 'reserve_huge_os_pages_at': -1
mimalloc: option 'reserve_os_memory': 0
mimalloc: option 'deprecated_segment_cache': 0
mimalloc: option 'page_reset': 0
mimalloc: option 'abandoned_page_decommit': 0
mimalloc: option 'deprecated_segment_reset': 0
mimalloc: option 'eager_commit_delay': 1
mimalloc: option 'decommit_delay': 25
mimalloc: option 'use_numa_nodes': 0
mimalloc: option 'limit_os_alloc': 0
mimalloc: option 'os_tag': 100
mimalloc: option 'max_errors': 16
mimalloc: option 'max_warnings': 16
mimalloc: option 'max_segment_reclaim': 8
mimalloc: option 'allow_decommit': 1
mimalloc: option 'segment_decommit_delay': 500
mimalloc: option 'decommit_extend_delay': 2
mimalloc: process init: 0x7f1869a34740
mimalloc: secure level: 0
```

So,i am confused:

- everything goes in the direction that the "mimalloc" allocator is currently in use (the jemalloc related environment variables have no effect...whereas the "mimalloc" related ones seems to have an effect)
- i am on a linux image and in theory the jemalloc allocator should be in use

I would then have the following questions:

- how can i check which allocator is currently in use ?
- if it is not Jemalloc, why it would be the case ?
- if it is Jemalloc, how can i some statistics displayed ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linux binaries we use jemalloc.

For windows binaries we use mimalloc.

Comment: thanks for confirming. Any idea why the mimalloc_verbose environment variable seems to have an effect…whereas the jemalloc related does not have any effect (not able to display the jemalloc statistics!)? I am on a linux image, so I expect the opposite. I am confused.

Comment: regarding the ability to get jemalloc stats, i was able to have them through the _RJEM_MALLOC_CONF env variable (instead of MALLOC_CONF). regarding the fact, that the mimalloc options are dumped when i set MIMALLOC_VERBOSE, it is still not clear to me (i would have expected no reference at all to mimalloc in the polars lib packaged for linux....but i may miss something).